# Handling namespace issues while transforming xml

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I am able to transform the xml as per my requirement with the below xml as the input.

```
<message
    xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <m_control>
    <control_timestamp>2013-06-06T14:55:37</control_timestamp>
    <initiator_id>ASL</initiator_id>
  </m_control>
  <m_content>
    <b_control>
      <quote_type>Single Company</quote_type>
      <quote_or_print>Quote And Print</quote_or_print>
      <generic_quote_ind>Yes</generic_quote_ind>
      <tpsdata>
        <tps_quote_type>Comparison</tps_quote_type>
      </tpsdata>
    </b_control>
    <application>
      <product>
        <tpsdata>
          <service_type>QuickQuote</service_type>
          <quote_type>Standard</quote_type>
        </tpsdata>
      </product>
    </application>
  </m_content>
</message>
```

But the problem is, sometimes the input XML will contain the refference to Namespace as a prefix to each element .As shown in the xml below the namespace prefix 'ns2' for each element.Below is the xml with 'ns2' namespace prefixes. In this case, my xslt fails and unable to perform the transformation. Could anyone please help me to understand how to handle this namespace issues in xslt,  so that xml with and without namespace prefixes can be transformed by the same xslt?

```
<ns2:message xmlns:ns2="http://www.origoservices.com"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
>
  <ns2:m_control>
    <ns2:control_timestamp>2013-06-06T14:55:37</ns2:control_timestamp>
    <ns2:initiator_id>ASL</ns2:initiator_id>
  </ns2:m_control>
  <ns2:m_content>
    <ns2:b_control>
      <ns2:quote_type>Single Company</ns2:quote_type>
      <ns2:quote_or_print>Quote And Print</ns2:quote_or_print>
      <ns2:generic_quote_ind>Yes</ns2:generic_quote_ind>
      <ns2:quote_response_status>Error</ns2:quote_response_status>
<ns2:tpsdata>
<ns2:tps_quote_type
xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com"
xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>Comparison</ns2:tps_quote_type>
</ns2:tpsdata>


    </ns2:b_control>
    <ns2:application>
      <ns2:product>
        <ns2:tpsdata>
          <ns2:service_type>QuickQuote</ns2:service_type>
          <ns2:quote_type>Standard</ns2:quote_type>
        </ns2:tpsdata>
      </ns2:product>
    </ns2:application>
  </ns2:m_content>
</ns2:message>
```

I am using below xslt.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:o="http://www.origoservices.com"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    extension-element-prefixes="dp"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn date">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="o:b_control/o:quote_type[../o:tpsdata/o:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:text>Comparison</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="o:tpsdata[o:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Let me know if more information is needed.

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: It shouldn't matter what prefixes are used (or if they are used) as long as the namespace URIs match, and they seem to in this case. What do you mean when you say the XSLT fails? It seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: I migt not be very clear while asking the question, appologies for that. Actually, it should replace the value of the <ns2:quote_type> element from 'Single company' to 'Comparison', in case <ns2:tps_quote_type> element is present and has the value 'Comparison'. This XSLT doesn't do the required transformation when 'ns2:' is prefixed for the elements in input xml. While it behaves as expected when, 'ns2:' is not prefixed.

Comment: When I run your XSLT against the second document, `ns2:quote_type` does indeed change from "Single company" to "Comparison". Perhaps there is a problem with your XSLT processor? What processor are you using?

Comment: Actually, I have just found out that, 'ns2:' is not an issue, actual issue is,in <tps_quote_type> there are below xml namespace refferences, I have updated the input xml in the question.Could you please check the same?

xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com"  xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Comment: The `<ns2:tps_quote_type>` element in your second example is in the `"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"` namespace, not in the `"http://www.origoservices.com"` namespace. Namespace declarations in this one element are swapped. That's your issue here, and I'm pretty sure that this is not intended.

Comment: Hello Tomalak,

I have updated the input xml accordingly, now there are below two namespaces declared in the input xml, xmlns:ns2="http://www.origoservices.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"

Is it possible to transform the xml to get the intended results?

Comment: Yes, it's possible:  write your XML to put elements in the namespaces they belong in, and then write your templates to match the elements you want them to match.  Your current problem is that your two inputs are not similar:  one has an element in {http://www.origoservices.com}tps_quote_type and one has the analogous element in {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}tps_quote_type

Comment: I have a question over here, as I am new to the XSLTs, I wonder, how would we get know that the <ns2:tps_quote_type> element in my second example is in the "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" namespace, not in the "http://www.origoservices.com" namespace?

Comment: Because it says so. `<ns2:tps_quote_type xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com"
xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">`. The element is in the namespace abbreviated as `ns2`, and `ns2` is defined as `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#` here.

Comment: ok, I understood it now. So basically, what is happening here, I am doing the transformation on the incoming xml which has been provided by a Java service. In some cases, the <ns2:tps_quote_type> is in  "http://www.origoservices.com" namespace, and in some cases, the <ns2:tps_quote_type> is part of http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" namespace. So, basically the I should update my code to make sure that both the cases should get handled, while transforming the xml.

Comment: Hello All, I have updated the code. I have updated the question with the new XSLT that I am using to handle this issue.

Comment: Yes, you *can* solve this in XSLT. But looking at the use case, I think the Java service is broken and should be fixed, instead of working around the issue in client code. `<tps_quote_type>` has nothing to do with XML signatures in your use case, so it should definitely never be in the XML Signature namespace.

Comment: Sure Tomalak, I have already told Java developers to fix this issue from there end, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: BTW, it's perfectly acceptable to write an answer to your own question on this website. A) you *did* solve it on your own, after all, B) the question would no longer appear as "unanswered", C) it's a lot better than writing the answer inside the question and D) you can even get upvotes for it.

Comment: I have implemented the above suggestions provided by Tomalak, I have removed the answer fro the question and answered the question seperately.

Answer (score 0):

After all the discussion on this forum, my issue has been resolved. Below is the corrected xslt to handle the namespace issues that I was facing.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:o="http://www.origoservices.com" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:g="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="fn date">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="o:b_control/o:quote_type[../o:tpsdata/g:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<xsl:text>Comparison</xsl:text>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="o:tpsdata[g:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']"/>
<xsl:template match="o:b_control/o:quote_type[../o:tpsdata/o:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<xsl:text>Comparison</xsl:text>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="o:tpsdata[o:tps_quote_type = 'Comparison']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```